# how can i connect a signal in one Qwidget to a slot in another Qwidget?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

am new to Qt and Qtcreator. 
Am working on a multi-widget application. My question is, is it possible to connect a signal in one Qwidget (say a submit button in edit contacts Qwidget) to a slot in another Qwidget(one showing the edited contacts) using the graphical signal-slot editor in Qtcreator.

From my interaction with the signal-slot editor, i can only drag the signal to another component withing the same widget, but not one outside of the widget. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK that's only possible for widgets in the same .ui file. You will need to do this in the generated code with `connect(widgetA, SIGNAL(signal()), widgetB, SLOT(slot());`

Comment: Actualy you can connect any two widgets, regardless of their location, as far as one can see the other. Being in the same .ui fits the description, However, any widget declared in the public section of a different class can be connected to a private (or public) widget in another class. If you are still dubious, just remember that you can connect the return signals of a dialog box (widget A) to slots in a main application (widget B). On a side note to okwii david: are all answers you were given wrong? If not, you should accept a few so that they keep coming.

Comment: So you agree that you cannot connect Signals and Slots between different forms (form1.ui and form2.ui) using only the GUI? I don't see anything in the interface. That's how I interpret the question.

Comment: You are right. I missed the QtCreator requirement, sorry. Indeed, I do not see any way to connect slots using the creator or the designer between different forms.

Comment: Thanks rpsml and atamanroman for that advice. Am still playing around with Qt creator and designer and how to connect signals and slots manually as in the above code connect(widgetA, SIGNAL(signal()), widgetB, SLOT(slot()); Thanks